# Irrelevant results in mysql full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a Mysql table set up for full text search across both the title and the content (body) columns.

I'm trying to bring the most relevant results to the top but I get a lot of garbage.

I have 3 full text indexes, one for the title, one for the body and one for both the title and the body so I can execute the following query:

```
SELECT id, url, title, body, earliestCapture, responseYear, urlScore,
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ("jurassic park" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS titleScore,
  MATCH (body) AGAINST ("jurassic park" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS bodyScore,
  (SELECT (titleScore * 100 + bodyScore)) AS finalscore
    FROM Entries
    WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ("jurassic park" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    ORDER BY finalScore DESC LIMIT 0,1000;
```

I'm trying to multiply the score of the title by 100 to bring instances where the term is in the title to the top.

This does help, but if the body has the word `park` repeated many times even without the word `Jurassic` appearing a single time, that row is propelled to the top of the search results.

A great example of that is when I search for "intel pentium". There are a few rows with bodies that use the word `intel` in the context of intelligence/information and not the company name, that word is repeated hundreds of times and even though there are no instances of the word `pentium`, those pages are always on the top.

I'm getting really annoyed by this. Does anyone know how to improve the search results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you ahev to add a + to both search terms so that only results are shown that have both see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

```
SELECT id, url, title, body, earliestCapture, responseYear, urlScore,
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ("+jurassic +park" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS titleScore,
  MATCH (body) AGAINST ("+jurassic +park" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS bodyScore,
  (SELECT (titleScore * 100 + bodyScore)) AS finalscore
    FROM Entries
    WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ("+jurassic +park" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    ORDER BY finalScore DESC LIMIT 0,1000;
```

Comment: Are you saying I should add that in my code before sending the request? What if the user enters the + and - symbols in the search box?

Comment: HAve you read the manual about searching full text indexes, as i posted the link to it a minus would exclude the word, so you have to have a gui where you can add all or some of the characters listed in the link and not allow leading or trailing - at allin the searchtext. please go to the link and read it carefully

Comment: I get how it works, I'm just saying that if a user just types "Jurassic Park" in the search they probably expect that results with both words will appear on the top, so if I add the + programmatically, I wonder what would I do if the user actually enters those characters.

Comment: no,. iimdb, uses elastic search and sort with the "relevanz value" descending, so with two words in it it should have a higher numbe than only one word, but this isn't what you asked for